# Problem saving data in mongodb after Stripe payment confirmation

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, stripe-payments

In the code below, I can't get "const res = await axios.post("/orders"..." to fire only after the "PAY NOW" button is confirmed. When the button. data backup is done before payment confirmation. While I want it to fire after confirmation and redirect to /success page.

```
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.

      return;
    }

    setIsProcessing(true);

    const res = await axios.post("/orders", {
      products: props.products.map((item) => ({
        productId: item._id,
        title: item.title,
        price: item.price,
        quantity: item._quantity,
      })),
      totalPrice: props.amount(),
    });

    console.log(res.data);
    dispatch(resetCart());

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
        return_url: `${window.location.origin}/success`,
      },
    });

    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
      setMessage(error.message);
    } else {
      setMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
    }
    setIsProcessing(false);
  };

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" />
      <button
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 mt-4 px-4 rounded"
        disabled={isProcessing || !stripe || !elements}
        id="submit"
      >
        <span id="button-text">
          {isProcessing ? "Processing ... " : "PAY NOW"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `confirmPayment` function can really only return one thing = an error.
If the function fails, the customer stays on the page, and any code can continue. If the function succeeds, your customer is redirected, and any code would be interrupted, which would explain why none of your code runs.

Something that would help is if you set `redirect:'if_required'` in the `confirmPayment` function, then your code should work (so long as the selected payment method type doesn't depend from a redirect):
https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-redirect

That said, handling this kind of process from the frontend is generally a bad idea, as it could be manipulated. You should perform these processes after getting a confirmation from trusted sources - ie getting notified from webhooks or polling the payment objects with GET requests:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status#webhooks